I am trying to solve a two point Boundary Value Problem using linear shooting method
Okay so I completely wrong
the Second order differential equation is
$$u''+(2/r) u' = 0, ~u(2)=110, ~u(4) =0\text{ we need to approximate} ~~u(3)$$
I start by converting this into IVP and finding $\phi(z)$
so we let $$u' = y, u(a)=110(given)$$ then $$u''= y' = (-2/r)y, y(a)=u'(a)=\alpha$$
Since we do not know what $u'(2)$ is we will guess and solve the IVP we have now
using MATLAB's ode45 to solve the IVP we start choosing/guessing values for alpha and then plotting all the curves we get

I believe there is a method by which we can guess alpha
for this I used a vector of the form $\alpha = -110:10:110$
Is this the correct approach

Yes, so far this is correct. Now use that the equation is linear, thus the solutions superpose, thus the value at the end of the interval is a linear function of the state at the start of the interval. As the value there is fixed, the only variable is $\alpha$.
To determine the linear function and with it its roots, you need only to compute two solutions and apply an interpolation formula. Or a reverse interpolation formula, both leading to the secant root formula. You might want to repeat this process once or twice with $\alpha$'s close to the current approximation or à la secant method to reduce the influence of floating point errors.
